# Prototype/Subclasses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor, prototype

I'm having trouble identifying whether or not I'm using prototypes/subclasses properly in JavaScript.

Here's this constructor function I have:

```
function SentientBeing(homePlanet, language) {
  this.homePlanet = homePlanet;
  this.language   = language;
}
```

And I am tasked with creating three 'subclasses' of SentientBeing. Would this be considered correct, or am I doing this improperly?
Thanks in advance.

```
// TODO: create three subclasses of SentientBeing, one for each
// species above (Klingon, Human, Romulan).
function Human() {
  SentientBeing.call(this, homePlanet, language);
}
function Romulan() {
  SentientBeing.call(this, homePlanet, language);
}
function Klingon() {
  SentientBeing.call(this,homePlanet, language);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to find out, what you want to achive here, but I will quickly show how to use prototypes:

```
function SomeClass() {
  this.a = 'a';
  this.b = 'b';
}

// Objects Method
SomeClass.prototype.methodHello = function( name ) {
  console.log('Hi, ' + name + '!');
};

// call this way:
var obj = new SomeClass();
obj.methodHello('Jose'); // => 'Hi, Jose!'

// Static Method
SomeClass.staticHello = function( name ) {
  console.log('Hello, ' + name  + '!');
};

// call this way:
SomeClass.staticHello('Herku'); // => 'Hello, Herku!'
```